# Discussing compactness

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$, the set of rational numbers, with the metric  $d(p,q)=|p-q|$.

Then is 
$\{q\in \mathbb{Q}\; |\; -2\leq q^2\leq 4\}$ 
compact?

I guess $q^2$ is effectively lying between 0 and 4. Since it is bounded and closed. So compact. But the answer key says it is not. I wonder how.

I also wonder what the importance of the given metric is.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really compact? Recall that a set in a metric space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded.

Note that the sequence $q_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k!}$ belongs to that set and it is a Cauchy sequence.

What is its limit? Is it rational?

Comment: It makes sense but I wonder why we are not taught this definition of compactness. Is it standard definition?

Comment: The proper general definition is yet another one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Definitions
The characterization of compactness depends on the topological space. Usually one starts with the basic case of $\mathbb{R}$ with the euclidean distance.

Comment: Does it mean if |p-q| were not given, we could have got different answer?

Comment: @Ramit Yes. The answer depends on the topology. For example consider $\mathbb{Q}$ with the trivial topology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology Then EVERY SUBSET of $\mathbb{Q}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "bounded and closed implies compact" is true in $\mathbb{R}$ (and in $\mathbb{R}^n$), but it is not true in general.  In particular, it is not true for $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be an increasing sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt {3/2}.$ Let $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a decreasing sequence of rationals converging to $\sqrt {3/2}.$

Let $S_n=[(-\infty,a_n)\cup (b_n,\infty)]\cap \mathbb Q.$ Since $\sqrt {3/2}$ is not rational, the set $\{S_n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is an open cover, in  $\mathbb Q,$ of your set. And this cover has no finite sub-cover. So your set is not compact.

A subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. This does not hold for all metric spaces.

Answer (score -1):

The set is not compact because it is not closed. The set has irrational limit points not contained in the set.

Comment: Note that the set _is_ closed as a subset of the rationals. What it is not is _complete_.